# Is there a prototype basis for every vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Bases for vector spaces are non-unique. Also, new bases can be generated from other bases very easily and formulaically.

Is there some "prototype" basis, which we could find for every vector space, that defines a specific relationship between the elements in and across the different vectors for every possible basis for the vector space?

In the same vein, how generally can we specify what a basis looks like for some vector space?

Comment: This is very vague.  What properties would distinguish a "prototype" basis from some run of the mill basis?

Comment: I mean there’s often a basis which is useful for your specific purposes. But what do you mean by prototype, or any of these words?

Comment: I think based on your last sentence, you may need to spend some more time with standard examples of constructing basis (maybe for $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$). A basis has a very concise definition for any vector space.

Comment: There are infinite dimensional vector spaces whom basis cannot even be constructed explicitly. So the existence of a canonical basis seems out of reach...

Comment: For specific examples of vector spaces there might be an obvious, simple choice of a basis, such as the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$. But in general no, there is no “prototype” basis. And the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$ is often not the best basis to use.

Comment: The question is vague as worded, but a vague comment in that spirit (using quotes to highlight vagueness) is that even in situations where $V$ and $W$ have "obvious" bases that they "come with" (e.g. $V=W=\mathbb{R}^n$), the kernels and ranges of linear transformations from $V$ to $W$, which are also vector spaces in their own right, tend not to "come with" such things, e.g., if $(e_i)$ is a basis for $V$ and $(f_j)$ is a basis for $W$, the vectors $(e_i)$ (resp. $(f_i)$) may not be in the kernel (resp. range) of a given $T: V \to W$, and the vectors $(T(e_i))$ may not be linearly independent

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the definition of a Vector Space which distiguishes one basis from another. It is a theorem, not part of the usual definition (dependent on the Axiom of Choice for general infinite dimensional vector spaces) that every vector space has a basis. So a basis is normally taken to be a defined concept in relation to a Vector Space.

Once a basis is chosen, everything can be defined relative to that basis. That's part of the point of a basis.

Many of the Vector Spaces we encounter (depending on our field of study) have extra structure, and in such cases there may be ways of identifying a special basis which respects that extra structure. For example, there is a very common basis for the Complex Numbers as an extension of the Reals - $\{1, i\}$: although we could choose $-i$ rather than $i$ since complex conjugation is an isomorphism, so even here there is a choice.

Answer (score -1):

For finite dimensional vector spaces (and even for separable infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces I suppose), one could argue that a kind of "prototype" basis can be defined. Seeing as all vector spaces of that kind are isomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^N$(or $\ell^2$ in the case of the Hilbert spaces), one could define that "prototype" basis to be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and the images of the respective isomorphism. For example, in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ we would have $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and in the space of polynomials of degree $1$ there would be in accordance to the standard isomorphism, the basis $\{  1, x\}$, as for the space of diagonal matrices we would have $\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 \\0 &0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 \\0 &1 \end{bmatrix}\}$ and so one and so forth.

While this might be something like what I think you were after, you can see how arbitrary it is. It not only requires us to "choose" a certain space from which to build a basis and from which the isomorphisms should take entries, but to choose that basis as well. So I don't think this construction is prototypical in any meaningful sense, and I don't think there can be any such idea. The appeal of a basis already lies partly in the freedom we have in choosing them to simplify an abstract problem.

Comment: If $V$ is a real vector space of dimension $n$, there are many different isomorphisms between $V$ and $\mathbb R^n$, so this doesn’t single out any particular basis of $V$ as being special.

Comment: @littleO Yeah, in the same way that everything else is, in this construction, the isomorphism is arbitrary. You just gotta pick one. But there usually is a canonical one, so I thought it might serve as an answer anyway